# Merge two columns by crossing in a large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose this dataframe:

```
x<-data.frame(id1=c("a","b","c"),vals1=1:3)
```

How can I achieve the following:

```
  NEW 
1   a
2   1
3   b
4   2
5   c
6   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is not a good practice to have data of mixed data types in the same column.

However, to answer the question you can transpose the dataframe and use `c` to get an output as a single vector which is used to create one-column dataframe.

```
data.frame(new = c(t(x)))

#  new
#1   a
#2   1
#3   b
#4   2
#5   c
#6   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Data: x => data.frame
x <- data.frame(id1 = c("a","b","c"), vals1 = 1:3)

# Allocate memory -- create empty character vector: NEW => character vector:
NEW <- vector("character", (ncol(x) * nrow(x)))

# Store the solution: y => data.frame
y <- data.frame(NEW = as.character(unlist(sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i){
      c(as.character(x$id1[i, drop = TRUE]), as.character(x$vals1[i, drop = TRUE]))
        }
      )
    )
  )
)
```